# TypeError when using ragged tensors in TensorFlow data pipeline

Tags: python, tensorflow, pipeline, tensorflow-datasets

I'm attempting to create a `tf.data` pipeline using `RaggedTensors` in TensorFlow, but I keep encountering a TypeError:

```
"Cannot convert the argument `type_value`: RaggedTensorSpec(TensorShape(\[None, 3\]), tf.int16, 1, tf.int64) to a TensorFlow DType."
```

I've provided my code below for reference:

```py
def data_generator():
    for label, file in enumerate(['a.npy', 'b.npy']):
        yield generate_sample(file), label

def generate_sample(file_path):
    sequence = load_npy_file(file_path)
    return tf.cast(tf.ragged.constant(generate_windows(sequence)), dtype=tf.int16)

def load_npy_file(file_path):
    data = np.load(file_path, allow_pickle=True)
    return data.astype(np.int16)

def generate_windows(sequence):
    windows = [sequence[i:i + 2] for i in range(len(sequence) - 2 + 1)]
    return np.array(windows, dtype=np.int16)

np.save('a.npy', np.array([1,2,3,4], dtype=np.int16))
np.save('b.npy', np.array([5,6,7,8,9], dtype=np.int16))
output_signature = (
        tf.RaggedTensorSpec(shape=(None, 2), dtype=tf.int16),
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32)
)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(data_generator, output_signature)
```

After inspecting the shapes of the generated RaggedTensors, I noticed that they are different from the one defined in the `output_signature`: `RaggedTensorSpec(TensorShape([3, None]), tf.int16, 1, tf.int32)` and `RaggedTensorSpec(TensorShape([4, None]), tf.int16, 1, tf.int32)`. Could this discrepancy be causing the error? I would greatly appreciate any insights or solutions to resolve this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The call to `from_generator()` in the last line seems to have an argument mismatch. From my side, this fixes the problem:

```py
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(data_generator, output_signature=output_signature)
```

See [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator:%7E:text=as%20described%20above.-,from_generator,-View%20source) of the function. The second argument is `output_types`, not signature.